# Health App : Data saved for a specific patient is being shown in detail view for other patients

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

**In my health app I am attempting to allow the user to enter patient symptom data and save it.**

My app contains `Identity`, `Symptom`, and `IdentitySymptom` models.

A `ManyToManyField` exists between the `Identity` and `Symptom`.

The  **IdentitySymptom** model contains both ForeignKey fields each referencing the **Identity** and **Symptom** model.

**In my views document I used class based views to ensure that each Symptom object I created was attached to a patient.**

> ***Problem***

Given the `ManyToManyField` relationship, if I update the `symptom object` then of course all the `patients objects` related to the `symptom object` will be updated. The issue is that when I create a new `patient object`, that object automatically has the symptom object of the previously created patients. That is a bug. The new patient object should not have any symptom because I have not created the `symptom object` related to it yet.

Each `nomenclature` and `description`field should be attached to the patient object for which it was created. However, each time the fields are populated and saved the `nomenclature` and `description` seen in all the patients created which is not what I want.

Below both Tashoy and Qadi have the same `nomenclature` and `description` but I only clicked the Tashoy Beckford anchor tag `nomenclature` and `description`

How do I ensure that only Tashoy Beckford has that `Symptom object` data.

Essentially I want to ensure the relevant symptoms connect to the relevant patients.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

> Here is the code :

---

**models**

```
class Identity(models.Model):

    NIS =models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    time_patient_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True )
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null = True)
    location  = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    born = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)

    patient_key = models.ManyToManyField('Symptom')

class Symptom(models.Model):

    nomenclature = models.CharField(max_length = 80, default = '')
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 1000, default = '')

class IdentitySymptom(models.Model):

    identity = models.ForeignKey(Identity)
    key_medical = models.ForeignKey(Symptom)
```

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView
from script.forms import  IdentityForm, MedicalForm
from script.models import Identity, Symptom, IdentitySymptom





class Identity_view(CreateView):


    model = Identity
    template_name = 'script/script.html'


    def get(self, request):

        form = IdentityForm()
        script = Identity.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        var = {'form':form, 'script':script}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)


    def post(self, request):
        form = IdentityForm(request.POST)
        being = None
        if form.is_valid():
            NIS = form.save(commit = False)
            NIS.user = request.user
            NIS.save()
            being = form.cleaned_data['NIS']
            form = IdentityForm()

            return redirect('script:script')

        var = {'form': form, 'being':being }


        return render(request, self.template_name, var)


class Identity_list_view(ListView):

    model = Identity

    template_name = 'script/identity_list.html'

    def get(self, request):

        form = IdentityForm()
        script = Identity.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        var = {'form':form, 'script':script}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)


class Medical_document(CreateView):

    model = Symptom
    template_name = 'script/medical_document.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):

        form = MedicalForm
        script = Symptom.objects.all()
        var = {'form':form, 'script':script, 'pk':pk}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)


    def post(self, request, pk):

        form = MedicalForm(request.POST)
        state = None
        if form.is_valid():

            manuscript = form.save(commit = False)

            manuscript.user = request.user


            state = form.cleaned_data['description']


            manuscript.save()
            patient = Identity.objects.get(pk=pk)

            medical_key = IdentitySymptom.objects.create(patient = patient,          manuscript = manuscript)

            medical_key.patient.patient_key.add(manuscript)

            form = MedicalForm()

            redirect('script:script')

        else:
            print(form.errors)
        var = {'form': form, 'state': state, 'pk':pk}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)
```

Comment: When you say that saving a `Symptom` for one patient affects the others do you mean creating a new `Symptom` or updating it's properties? Updating the properties will of course update them for all patients with a link to that particular symptom. Have you tested your models using the Django shell?

Comment: @AndrewS I mean that if I update or create, those activities affect all the patients that I have created, which is not what I want.

Yes I have tested the models in the shell. Is there an approach to shell testing that you think will help.

Comment: Have you tried it in the Django shell to eliminate problems with the views and confirm your understanding of the data models? Updating the nomenclature and description of a symptom will affect all patients linked to that symptom. Are you saying you want the nomenclature and description to be unique for each customer (in which case a many to many relationship isn't the correct model) or when you save/update erroneous links are being created for other customers?

Comment: @AndrewS I want the symptom object i.e. nomenclature, and description to be connected to the patient for which it is created.

 [Here is a link to my repository](https://github.com/iivri/script)

Comment: @AndrewS I now understand what you first question means. Given the `ManyToManyField` relationship, if I update the symptoms objects then of course all the patients objects related to the object will be updated. 

The issue is that when I create a patient object, that object automatically has the symptom object of the previously created patients. That is a bug. The new patient object should not have any symptom because I have not created it yet.

Comment: Hi, I've looked at your repository and the problem is with the view. You're not filtering the symptoms for the user. You're displaying all symptoms. You need to modify the queryset in `Medical_document_list` to filter by the user in the URL.

Comment: I would also consider renaming `IdentitySymptom` or even removing it if you're not adding additional fields. I would rename it to something like `Consultation` and add a date. This would fit "A patient has zero, one or many consultations, each consultation has zero, one or many symptoms"

Comment: @AndrewS Could you give me an example using code?